# problem with installation jboss 7 in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, server, jboss

```
$ /opt/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/bin/standalone.sh
=========================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: /opt/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final

  JAVA: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_32/bin/java

  JAVA_OPTS:  -server -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djboss.server.default.config=standalone.xml

=========================================================================

/opt/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/bin/standalone.sh: 1: eval: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_32/bin/java: not found
```

Answer (score 0):

`/opt/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/bin/standalone.sh: 1: eval: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_32/bin/java: not found`

A Java 6 installation on your computer was not found in its default place, you should install Java 6 from the Software center or grab the package. If you already have a Java 6 installation, you should make sure it's installed in the right path, is up to date, and is the right version for your program.

All the program is trying to do is run a Java application using that specific Java version: 1.6.0_32. Simply install it the default way and you should be good to go.